# The authenticity and true meaning of this hadith: Abu bakr (Ra)and Umar (Ra) are the Masters of the Adults of Paradise

Tags: hadith, source-identification, hadith-interpretation, authenticity

I hear this hadith a lot:

> قال رسول الله: عمر وابوبکر سیداکهول اهل الجنة
>
> Abu Bakr and Umar are the Masters of  The Adults of Paradise.

Is it fabricated or not? Because there are similar hadith which express that **Hasan and Hussain are the Masters of the Youths of Paradise**. Some scholars believe that the first hadith is fabricated because of a famous hadith Hasan and Hussain are the Masters of the Youths of Paradise.

Answer (score 3):

This hadith was narrated different ways but most Islamic scholars believe that it is fabricated. Also, in content it is not true, because there are a lot of hadiths which mentioned every one enters in the heaven is youth not adult.
Here are some hadiths which prove that everyone in the heaven is youth:

> حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ بَشَّارٍ، وَأَبُو هِشَامٍ الرِّفَاعِيُّ
>   قَالاَ حَدَّثَنَا مُعَاذُ بْنُ هِشَامٍ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ، عَنْ عَامِرٍ
>   الأَحْوَلِ، عَنْ شَهْرِ بْنِ حَوْشَبٍ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، قَالَ
>   قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ أَهْلُ الْجَنَّةِ جُرْدٌ
>   مُرْدٌ كُحْلٌ لاَ يَفْنَى شَبَابُهُمْ وَلاَ تَبْلَى ثِيَابُهُمْ ‏"‏
>
> Abu Hurairah narrated from the Messenger of Allah (s.a.w) that he
>   said: "The people of Paradise are without body hair, Murd, with
>   Kuhl(on their eyelids), their youth does not come to an end, and their
>   clothes do not wear out."
>
> http://sunnah.com/urn/678450

Al-Suyuti in Dur al-Manthur in tafsir narrated that:

> وأخرج ابن أبي شيبة وأحمد وابن أبي الدنيا في صفة الجنة والطبراني في
>   الكبير عن أبي هريرة قال قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم يدخل أهل
>   الجنة الجنة جردا مردا بيضا جعادا مكحلين أبناء ثلاث وثلاثين. (volume
>   one, page48)

Heysami in Majmaol Zawahid narrated that:

> وعن أنس بن مالك قال قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم يدخل أهل الجنة
>   الجنة جردا مردا مكحلين. رواه الطبراني في الأوسط واسناده جيد
>   (volume10,page398-399)

Comment: You may want to add that the hadith is not authentic.

Answer (score 2):

Both *ahadith* about Abu Bakr and Umar, Hassan and Husain are not authentic.

The one about Abu Bakr and Umar =

> قال رسول الله: عمر وابوبکر سیداکهول اهل الجنة

It was collected in *Sunan ibn Majah* and similar ones in *Jami at-Tirmidhi*.

*Isnad* from Sunan ibn Majah =

> حَدَّثَنَا هِشَامُ بْنُ عَمَّارٍ، حَدَّثَنَا سُفْيَانُ، عَنِ الْحَسَنِ
>   بْنِ عُمَارَةَ، عَنْ فِرَاسٍ، عَنِ الشَّعْبِيِّ، عَنِ الْحَارِثِ، عَنْ
>   عَلِيٍّ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ

**هِشَامُ بْنُ عَمَّار** is not reliable and he often makes mistakes as mentioned by Imam n-Nasai.

**ْ الْحَسَنِ بْنِ عُمَارَةَ** he was abandoned and his narrations aren't accepted.

**الحارث** His full name was **الحارث بن عبد الله الأعور** and he was known to be a compulsive liar.

So this narration from *Sunan ibn Majah* is completely rejected.
There are other ones in *Jami at-Tirmidhi* which were declared as strange by Imam at-Tirmidhi.

As for the one mentioning Hassan and Husain being masters of youth in Paradise.  They're also inauthentic and cannot be proven to be true.

The *isnad* from *Jami at-Tirmidhi* =

> حَدَّثَنَا مَحْمُودُ بْنُ غَيْلاَنَ، حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو دَاوُدَ
>   الْحَفَرِيُّ، عَنْ سُفْيَانَ، عَنْ يَزِيدَ بْنِ أَبِي زِيَادٍ، عَنِ
>   ابْنِ أَبِي نُعْمٍ، عَنْ أَبِي سَعِيدٍ الْخُدْرِيِّ،

First problem is **سفيان** whose full name is **سفيان الثوري** and he was *mudallis*.  He's a reliable only when he narrates *ahadith* by saying he heard or he was told.  But not when he says "from - An" as he did here.  Therefore, it's not accepted.

Second problem is **يزيد بن أبي زياد** and he was declared as *munkar al hadith* by Imam al-Bukhari.

Therefore, because of these two people, this *hadith* is not authentic.

There are other *isnad* and Imam at-Tirmidhi said they were strange.

So both of the reports you've mentioned are rejected.

Comment: You may also want to say that this is from the sunni view point.

Comment: this hadith was narrated different ways but most islamic scholars believe that it is fabricated.also, in content it is not true, because there are a lot of hadiths which mentioned every one enters in the heaven is youth not adult.

Comment: the hadith of the Masters of the Youths of Paradise are mutewatir and it is narrated in different narattors and ways also it is so famous between shia and sunni scholars. i think it is better to explain this hadith in seprated guestion.

Comment: Those hadiths are falsely attributed to the Prophet.